# Docker-Compose results in The platform targeted with the current context is not supported

Tags: docker-compose

I am running local testing on macOS using `docker-compose` and I believe I'm following the [getting started documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) exactly. But I get the following error:

```
% docker-compose up
ERROR: The platform targeted with
the current context is not supported.
Make sure the context in use
targets a Docker Engine.
```

Any idea why that is happening? Docker Desktop is running.

Versions:

- OSX 12.2.1
- Docker Desktop 4.5.0
- docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
- docker-py version: 5.0.0

Key files:

Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **docker compose up** instead of **docker-compose up**.
Also if you are deploying to ECS, the asymmetrical **port mapping** **"8000:5000"** will not work. The **port mapping** has to be symmetrical.
Lastly, if you are deploying to ECS, the **build** will not work as expected. You can read more about the supported fields here.
https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-compose-features/. So you have to **build the image** in your local and **tag** it as <accontId>.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<imageName> and push it to ecs and use the image in your docker-compose file.